# Add/edit files inside a docker container using a remotely?

Tags: docker, ansible

I am new to both docker and ansible.

I am using ansible-playbook to

- Remotely login into a server
- Pull docker images from docker hub
- Create a new container.

I now want to add/edit some files to the container and run some pre-installed programs on the container.Is there a way to do so without opening the terminal and doing it manually?

Comment: Containers are supposed to be immutable, right? You can't expose a volume and edit files there?

Comment: Yes we cannot edit the files if they are mounted. But I have multiple files that need to be used on multiple containers. So even if i edit the files(via the host) while they are mounted it may create conflicts between two containers so I was hoping for another way.

Answer (score 0):

> > > add/edit some files to the container

`docker cp`for copying files to the container, see the doc

http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cp/

`docker exec -it container_id bash`and then or commands or 
`docker exec -it container_id sh -c awk...`

see the doc

http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/

> > > run some pre-installed programs

`docker exec -it container_id sh -c "run your program"`

Comment: docker cp only allows to copy files from the container to the host not the other way around.. and using -c if i run a program i still cannot enter the input text  for example if I run my program which accepts user-name and password and then only starts

Comment: correct, I was anticipating 1.8 extract from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/docker-user/MyMiiqBDKwU/Tgnl-dNnL4AJ "+ Allow to copy files from host to containers with `docker cp`"  Just upgrade to 1.8.0-rc1  and it is ok :-)

Comment: "using -c if i run a program " when you use `dockder exec` it is a good idea to add `-it` as i stands for interactive and t for a tty. Can you post your whole command line?

Comment: using -i -t puts the container into input mode so i have to manually enter the details that is the thing i am hoping to avoid, also i need to keep the program running as a background process so i cannot just exit it after entering the details.

Comment: try something like `docker exec -d ubuntu_bash touch /tmp/execWorks` from the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: For the copy from the host to the container, a trick "cat /local/file/path | docker exec -i <running-container-id> sh -c 'cat > /inside/docker/file/path'

Add tar and you will be able to copy folders as well.
"' this is extracted from https://forums.docker.com/t/will-docker-cp-command-work-for-copying-files-from-host-to-a-container/2022